# Picking only images from gallery Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I use

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, null), Photo.REQUEST_PICK_FROM_EXISTING);
```

Only images are getting displayed and with an option to use third party file manager apps which shows videos too. I want user to choose third party apps but choose only images. Is there any way to control it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
     Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
     photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Hope this helps.